# Wordpress doesn't show me as login at homepage

Tags: wordpress, session, cookies, authentication, woocommerce

I logged into my wordpress which uses woocommerce plugin.  When I am at homepage, I am not showing as logged in.  When I am at other pages though, I am showing as I am logged in.

I am trying to see why this is happening all of sudden?

Comment: Do you mean that on your homepage you do not see the admin bar at the top? This is likely an issue with your theme. What theme are you using and have you recently made any modifications to it?

Comment: the strange thing is that other staging website in the same server (using subdomain) are having the same issue as well.  One is a totally different theme and plugins are different too.  Main site is Avada, and one of staging website is Genesis.

Comment: and yes, I do not see the admin bar at the top cuz i am not logged in.  Then I click other pages and i show as logged in and the admin bar shows up.  Now this is happening to contact us page now..  I only did some cosmetic changes to the main website.

Comment: I suppose the next thing to trouble shoot would be what they have in common with one another. Outside of WooCommerce, what plugins or customizations do they both have in common, since they share the same issue?

Comment: I used woocommerce "clear session" button to clear up some sessions and still this is happening.  I know varnish cache is turned off.  Anyone had this similar issue?

Comment: Perhaps a quick check would be to place this in the functions.php to determine if you can override anything that may be setting this to false `show_admin_bar( true );` Perhaps also try and purge your cache if there are any files leftover. Typically though caching plugins should be disabled for the admin anyhow.

Comment: you mean my webbrowser cache? or cache from server side? i just checked all, none of the website use any caching plugins.  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable your plugins, and perhaps a quick check would be to place this in the `functions.php` to determine if you can override anything that may be setting this to false `show_admin_bar( true );`